# Using shared memory from different threads

Tags: multithreading, swift

I have a strange issue with multi-threading. I want to print a table view and therefore start a new thread which runs with a progress bar. Eventually this thread dies with memory errors for which I'm seeking the cause. Right now I got

> malloc: *** error for object 0x10000078c: Invalid signature for
>   pointer dequeued from free list**
>    set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug CaLister(27054,0x7fff73ea3300) malloc:  **error for object
>   0x60800043bcc0: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

But most of the times (still it happens rarely!) it just stops with no specific (but definitely memory related) error. When I look from the debugger my data are `nil`. But they have not been touched since they are still being available for display in my table view.

Now the question: is there any precaution I need to take to access data being allocated in the main thread so I can safely access them from the detached thread?

**Edit:** 
My print thread is dispatched like this (stripped code):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) { self.performPrint  (true) }

func  performPrint (async:Bool) {
  //First get the shared print info object so we know page sizes.  The shared print info object acts like a global variable.
  let sharedPrintInfo = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo()

  let printObject = PSPrint ()

  //Allocate a new instance of NSView into the variable printPageView
  var frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sharedPrintInfo.paperSize.width-sharedPrintInfo.leftMargin-sharedPrintInfo.rightMargin, height: sharedPrintInfo.paperSize.height-sharedPrintInfo.topMargin-sharedPrintInfo.bottomMargin)
  let basePrintPageView = PSPrintView(frame: frame)

  var printPageView:PSPrintView
  for pageNo in 1...paperDimensions.pages {
    paperDimensions.pageNo = pageNo

    printPageView = basePrintPageView.clone(pageNo)

    //Set the option for the printView for what it should draw.
    paperDimensions.pageNo = pageNo

    //Finally append the view to the PSPrint Object.
    printObject.printViews.append(printPageView)
  }
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    printObject.printTheViews() //print all the views, each view being a 'page'.
  }
}
```

Within

```
printPageView = basePrintPageView.clone(pageNo)
```

the access to my table view (where I get the data to be printed) returns nil sometimes.

**Edit2:** I just noticed that it's not the background thread which crashed, but the main thread :-/ Scratching my head even more but likely I have to close this question.

Comment: We can't help you at all unless you post ALL your related code.

Comment: @DuncanC as said it's not a small single place. I was hoping for something like "shared memory locking mechanism" I missed. Most likely it's simply a compiler/OS bug since I do not allocate memory myself. So I have no explanation why the detached thread finds nil where the main thread still finds (/should find) its data from the still existing table view.

Comment: You can use ViewObject in the background thread. 
> //Allocate a new instance of NSView into the variable printPageView
You can manipulate UI only, Only in the main thread. You should calculate data data and pass in to the main thread to show it.

Comment: @KostiantynKoval But the data in the main thread stay unchanged while the background thread runs. Why do I need to copy data?

Comment: You don't need to copy memory. Memory is shared across all threads/processes. What you do have to do is to make sure that if a thread is writing to memory, no other thread is reading and writing to the same memory. For that you need locks. The same is true for memory that is allocated by system APIs from a background thread.

Comment: Lots of system APIs are not safe from background threads. (Almost all of UIKit is not thread-safe.)

Comment: Explaining the subtleties of concurrent programming is beyond the scope of an SO thread. I suggest you do a LOT of reading. It's a complex subject with lots and lots of gotchas and opportunities for subtle, non-deterministic bugs that are all but impossible to track down.

Comment: @DuncanC I'm (almost) aware of that. But actually I'm not doing anything which touches that (i.e. not cross changing memory). I'm just accessing memory which is supposed to be there. See my **Edit2** above...